# Decimal point in LaTeX Math Mode

Tags: math-mode, xetex, punctuation

I am writing a large document with equations in LaTeX.  I suddenly noticed that a small unusual problem is occurring.  I am writing an equation as follows:

```
\begin{equation}
f_{c}(t) = 1.0 + 0.024 C(t) - 3.5\cdot10^{-3} C(t)^{2} + 2.8\cdot10^{-4} C(t)^{3}
\end{equation}
```

but the result of this in my final pdf looks like

```
f_{c}(t) = 1 0 + 0 024 C(t) - 3 5\cdot10^{-3} C(t)^{2} + 2 8\cdot10^{-4} C(t)^{3}
```

That is, all decimal points disappeared and were generated like a whitespace.  I cannot find any reason why this is happening.  How can I fix this?

---

@Herbert
concerning Fonts, i am now loading this :

```
\usepackage{xunicode}
\usepackage{xltxtra}
\defaultfontfeatures{Mapping=tex-text} % converts LaTeX specials (``quotes'' --- dashes etc.) to unicode
\setromanfont [Ligatures={Common}, BoldFont={Times New Roman}, ItalicFont={Times New Roman}]{Times New Roman}
\setsansfont [Ligatures={Common}, BoldFont={Calibri}, ItalicFont={Calibri}]{Calibri}
\setmonofont[Scale=0.8]{Monaco}
```

@Seamus
my working file looks like this, as an example for equation

```
\input preamble
\begin{document}
\selectlanguage{english}
\begin{equation}
\epsilon_{clear}(t) = 0.711 + 5.6\cdot10^{-3}\ \vartheta_{dew}(t)
\end{equation}
\end{document}
```

where my preamble is following layout file:

```
\usepackage[squaren]{SIunits}
\usepackage{cite,xunicode,xltxtra}    
\defaultfontfeatures{Mapping=tex-text}
\setromanfont [Ligatures={Common}, BoldFont={Times New Roman}, ItalicFont={Times New Roman}]{Times New Roman}
\setsansfont [Ligatures={Common}, BoldFont={Calibri}, ItalicFont={Calibri}]{Calibri}
\setmonofont[Scale=0.8]{Monaco} 

% HEADINGS
\usepackage{sectsty} 
\usepackage[normalem]{ulem}
\chapterfont{\sffamily\bfseries\upshape\Huge}
\sectionfont{\sffamily\bfseries\upshape\Large}
\subsectionfont{\sffamily\bfseries\upshape\large} 
\subsubsectionfont{\sffamily\bfseries\upshape\normalsize} 

\RequirePackage[times]{quotchap}
\renewcommand{\sectfont}{\sffamily\bfseries\upshape\Huge}

\makeatletter
\newcommand\citaat{\if@openright\cleardoublepage\else\clearpage\fi\thispagestyle{plain}}

% chapters that do not start at new page...
\newcommand\chapterNoPageBreak{\thispagestyle{plain}\global\@topnum\z@\@afterindentfalse\secdef\@chapter\@schapter}  
\makeatother

\usepackage[dutch,english]{babel}

\usepackage{fancyhdr,graphicx,listings}
\renewcommand\lstlistlistingname{List of Listings} % default is Listings
\lstset{language=JAVA}

\usepackage{fancyhdr}
\pagestyle{fancyplain}

\usepackage{moreverb}

\addtolength{\headheight}{3pt}         % allow 1 lines in 12pt
\renewcommand{\headrulewidth}{0.4pt}
\renewcommand{\footrulewidth}{0pt}
\renewcommand{\plainheadrulewidth}{0pt}
\renewcommand{\plainfootrulewidth}{0pt}

\renewcommand{\chaptermark}[1]{\markboth{#1}{}}
\renewcommand{\sectionmark}[1]{\markright{\thesection\ #1}}

\lhead[\fancyplain{}{\rm\thepage}]{\fancyplain{}{\rightmark}}
\chead[]{}
\rhead[\fancyplain{}{\leftmark}]{\fancyplain{}{\rm\thepage}}
\lfoot[]{}
\cfoot[]{\fancyplain{\rm\thepage}{}}
\rfoot[]{}

\input{macros.def}
```

...

Comment: which font are you loading?

Comment: Please add a [minimal working example (MWE)](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/questions/228/ive-just-been-told-i-have-to-write-a-minimal-example-what-is-that) that illustrates your problem.

Comment: This is not a problem of the zoom level in your viewer? The Preview app on Mac OS X sometimes does not show hyphens when zoomed out but they are there.

Comment: @Christian
No, it is not a problem of my pdf reader, the dots are actually missing, i.e. in my pdf as well as on paper if i print it :)

Comment: [Welcome to TeX.sx!](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/questions/1436/welcome-to-tex-sx) Your question was migrated here from another stackexchange site. Please register on this site, too, and make sure that both accounts are associated with each other, otherwise you won't be able to comment on or accept answers or edit your question.

Comment: I don't know if this will solve the problem, but you have to leave an empty space between, for example, `\cdot` and `10` or you'll get an error. Anyway, your example isn't complete because the class is missing and you do not show the `macros.def` file. Try to make it really minimal and report (if any) the errors that you get.

Comment: @Spike: actually, that does not seem to be the case. rubae:  my guess is that there is some problem with the fonts you use.  I don't have any of the fonts, so I cannot check that. Is there anything in your log file that would indicate any sort of font problem? As Seamus and Spike already mentioned, you should really try to produce a minimal working example demonstrating the problem.  I tried to create one, but without the fonts, I was not able to recreate the problem.

Comment: I indeed find several errors in my log file which state Unknown feature `' in font `Times New Roman'. but further than this i find nothing explicetely for this problem ... R

Comment: After removing line by line everything in my preamble, the cause seems to lies in \usepackage{SIunits} which seems to recognize the decimal point in the equations as seperator for 'thousands' and makes it a space. R

Comment: This example is neither minimal nor working. If no one can reproduce your error, then it is difficult for anyone to help you.

Comment: @ruben: The answer section is indented for solutions to the stated question only. Please edit the question or add comments to provide more information. However, you still need to connect your stackoverflow and your local account together. For this you need to register on both sides.

Comment: If you switch the to `siunitx` package, does this change anything?

Comment: @ruben baetens: Please a *minimal* example that shows the problem; otherise , we'll have to close this question.